# Error inflating class fragment google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to get this tutorial work:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm

This is the code:

```
public class ViewMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    static final LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21 , 57);
       private GoogleMap googleMap;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_map);
          try { 
                if (googleMap == null) {
                   googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                }
             googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
             Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint).title("TutorialsPoint"));

          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }

       }
}
```

The layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context="com.androidpoiservice.ViewMapActivity" >

  <fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

And the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidpoiservice"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


<permission
  android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidpoiservice.StartUpActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_up"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidpoiservice.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidpoiservice.RegisterActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidpoiservice.MainMenuActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidpoiservice.AddPOIActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_poi"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidpoiservice.ViewMapActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_map"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAgjXQt9zYFw5m0t7BIhxGT6e82mnZQUEA" />

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

This is the error I get :

```
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidpoiservice/com.androidpoiservice.ViewMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.androidpoiservice.ViewMapActivity.onCreate(ViewMapActivity.java:32)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     ... 11 more
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ex(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
03-13 20:21:23.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this as a meta tag as a child of application tag

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
     ...// rest of the code
    </activity>
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- Goolge API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="api key" />
 </application>
```

Change this

```
public class ViewMapActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

to

```
public class ViewMapActivity extends Activity
```

Edit:

Uncomment

```
 //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: @GeorgePanic no you can't get the same error. No way. make the changes re-run and then post the updated code and stacktrace

Comment: You're right it worked after I removed the comment on the code ://super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); now on the emulator it says I have to update google play services

Comment: @GeorgePanic you need to test it on a real device. Emulator does not have google play services isntalled.

Comment: i have installed it like this:http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/

Comment: @GeorgePanic better test it on a real device. On;y 4.1.2 or more i guess has google play service. that too you need google api's. So testing on a real device is a better option

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a device. This is what log cat displayed:03-13 20:47:27.539: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1375): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 2010110

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49682/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-george-panic)